# istio routing http to https upstream causes causes 302

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio

My ingress gateway is at port 80 http and routing to a https destination.

With the following configuration

```
http://ingress-gateway.example.com/zzz
```

it gives `302` and the urls changes to **https**:

```
https://my-site.example.com/products
```

Why `302` and what am I missing?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port: # Note: I am entering using this port
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port: # Note: I am NOT entering using this port
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      credentialName: my-credential

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: apps-domain
spec:
  hosts:
  - my-site.example.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https-my-site
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
- match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /zzz
    rewrite:
      uri: /products
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 443
        host: my-site.example.com

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: my-https-backend
spec: 
  host: my-site.example.com
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      sni: my-site.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a rewrite rule pointing to port 443

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
- match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /zzz
    rewrite:
      uri: /products
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 443 # here
        host: my-site.example.com
```

Comment: So I should remove `rewrite:`  ? Then how do I hit `my-site.example.com/product` ?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Its not working for what I am trying to do which is basically enter as HTTP and proxy to a HTTPS endpoint without generating redirects. Any typical API gateways can do this.

Comment: Change the port number to 80 in route destination. It should work.